# getView() called with same position

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, getview

the getView() method in my custom adapter that extends ArrayAdapter is called with the same position value more than once. I tried the custom adapter and it worked when the ArrayList I provided had 5 items and it's not working as expected when the ArrayList has 3 items.

Here is the code

```
public class ShowSchedule extends Activity {
    private DBHelper db;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_courses);
        db = new DBHelper(this);
        String stdID = HomePage.STD_ID;
        ListView mainList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_courses);
        ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();

        Cursor cursor = db.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DBHelper.TIME_COURSE_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " +
                DBHelper.TIME_COURSE_COLUMN_COURSE_ID + " IN (SELECT " + DBHelper.STD_COURSE_COLUMN_COURSEID + 
                " FROM " + DBHelper.STD_COURSE_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + DBHelper.STD_COURSE_COLUMN_STDID + 
                " = " + stdID + ")");

        String courseID = "", timeID = "", day = "";
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            courseID = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.TIME_COURSE_COLUMN_COURSE_ID));
            Cursor temp = db.executeQuery("SELECT " + DBHelper.COURSE_COLUMN_NAME + " FROM " + DBHelper.COURSE_TABLE_NAME 
                    + " WHERE " + DBHelper.COURSE_COLUMN_ID + " = " + courseID);
            temp.moveToFirst();
            String courseName = temp.getString(temp.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COURSE_COLUMN_NAME));
            temp = db.executeQuery("SELECT " + DBHelper.ROOM_COURSE_COLUMN_ROOM_ID + " FROM " +
            DBHelper.ROOM_COURSE_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + DBHelper.ROOM_COURSE_COLUMN_COURSE_ID + " = " + courseID);
            temp.moveToFirst();
            String room = temp.getString(temp.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.ROOM_COURSE_COLUMN_ROOM_ID));
            timeID = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.TIME_COURSE_COLUMN_TIME_ID));
            day = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.TIME_COURSE_COLUMN_DAY));
            entries.add(new Entry(courseID, courseName, timeID, day, room));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        CoursesAdapter adapter = new CoursesAdapter(this, entries);

        mainList.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

and the adapter

```
public class CoursesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Entry> {

    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<Entry> entries;

    public CoursesAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Entry> objects) {
        super(context, R.layout.activity_list_item, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.entries = objects;
    }

    private final String[] days = { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu" };
    @Override
    public int getCount() { 
        return entries.size();
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.activity_list_item, parent, false);
        int[] id = {
                R.id.tvCourseName1,
                R.id.tvCourseName2,
                R.id.tvCourseName3,
                R.id.tvCourseName4,
                R.id.tvCourseName5,
                R.id.tvCourseName6
        };

            TextView tvDay = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txDay);
            tvDay.setText(days[position]);      
            for (Entry e : entries) {
                if (e.getDay().equals(days[position])) {
                    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(id[Integer.parseInt(e.getTimeID()) - 1]);
                    tv.setText(e.getInfo());
                }
            }

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Blackbelt but my android:layout_height is already match_parent..!

Comment: *This is not an issue, there is absolutely no guarantee on the order in which getView() will be called nor how many times.*